# PeronaMalikFilter for 3D image

Tags: image-processing, image3d

Is there any other way to use PeronaMalikFilter for 3D images apart from using a loop to run through all the slices?

**What I tried to do**

```
slices = Image3DSlices[img];
{ht, wd, nsl} = ImageDimensions[img];

Do[fl[[i]] = PeronaMalikFilter[sl[[i]], 10], {i, nsl}];
```

The above code is showing me some error and furthermore it's taking a very long time.

Comment: Have a look at `Map`

Comment: I don't know how this can help me with the image slices.

Comment: You could write a short function that applies your filter to a single image (slice) and test this. When you are sure your filter functions works as intended you apply it to all the slices via `Map`

Comment: Applying to each slice is not the same things as applying it to a 3D image.  The 3D neighbourhood matters.  You'd have to use an external tool such as ITK or ImageJ to get this functionality.

Comment: @Szabolcs I just assumed the OP wanted to treat each slice as an individual image since `PersonaMalikFilter` does not seem to support 3D images out of the box

Comment: Yes, PeronaMalikFilter is not supporting 3D images. However, my objective is to apply it for 3D image.

Comment: Mathematica simply doesn't have this functionality.  There is no easy way to do it.  You either have to implement it from scratch, or use an external tool (possibly hook up an external tool to Mathematica).  You can also use a MATLAB implementation and call it through MATLink (if you have MATLAB).